# Nested Join to combine 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have a partner form that requires the user to log in before they can use the app. It has 3 tables that, when combined, provide the app with all of the user’s pertinent session ID information. This is also used by the app to determine pre-populated fields and user permission.

[View Tables Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPyTQ.png)

I believe I need to do a nested join to combine these three tables together, but I am not sure how to do it.
The query should combine all of the columns from all 3 tables into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using simple inner join.

You can try following query.

```
select * from users a, partners b, partnerLevels c
where a.partnerID = b.partnerID
and b.partnerLevel = c.partnerLevel
```

Hope it will help.